# How to verify version format in powershell script?

Tags: shell, version, powershell-3.0

So I am trying to verify if a provided version number is valid or not in powershell with the following code:

```
$ParsedVersion=''

if ([System.Version]::TryParse("1.2.3.43", [ref]$ParsedVersion)) {
    Write-Host ("valid version")
}
else {
    Write-Host ("invalid version")
}
```

but I keep getting the error *Exception calling "TryParse" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Version". Error: "Version
string portion was too short or too long.""*

I tried lots of different ways but still no luck. I am wondering if there exists a right way to do this? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do this instead

```
$ParsedVersion = $null
```

it should work..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
$version = "1.2.3.43"
$IsValid = & {
      try {
        [bool][version]$Version
      } catch [System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException], [System.ArgumentException] {
        # The version is invalid, too long or too short.
        $false
      } catch {
        # definetly not because the version is invalid
        throw $_.Exception
      }
}
if ($IsValid) {
    Write-Host ("valid version")
} else {
    Write-Host ("invalid version")
}
```